# function calls in angular JS controller are executed in random order

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

```
app.controller('attributeFormCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$log', '$modalInstance', 'attributeService', function($scope, $route, $log, $modalInstance, attributeService) {

    $scope.someMethod = function(){
        attributeService.getAllAttributeTypes().then(function(response){
            $scope.attributeTypes=response.data;
            }, function(error){
                // some error occurred
        });

        attributeService.getAttributeById($scope.attributeId).then(function(response){
            $scope.attribute=response.data;
        },function(error) {
            // error occurred.
        });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
          $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.someMethod();
}]);
```

Comment: when i debug on chrome, sometimes getAttributeById is called first and sometimes getAllAttributeTypes.......this might be a stupid question but i am new to angular!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using asynchronous methods that returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Depending on a ton of factors, one might finish before the other, as you've found out.

If you need one to execute before the other, you can call one before the other, and then call the other within the callback function, as such:

```
$scope.someMethod = function(){
    attributeService.getAllAttributeTypes().then(function(response){
        $scope.attributeTypes=response.data;

        attributeService.getAttributeById($scope.attributeId).then(function(response){
            $scope.attribute=response.data;
        },function(error) {
            // error occurred.
        });
    }, function(error){
        // some error occurred
    });
};
```

That way you'll always be sure of which one finishes first.

Comment: i just did exactly that before coming here, thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no random in JavaScript.

In your case, `getAllAttributeTypes` function is called first, then `getAttributeById`, BUT, the `.then()` means there is a callback and function `getAllAttributeTypes` will take sometimes more time than the second one, that's why `$scope.attributeTypes=response.data;` is called after `$scope.attribute=response.data;` in some cases.

This is not an Angular specificity, but a JavaScript one.

Comment: thanks for explaining that. i wanted to call them in a specific order.... i did what jValdron suggested(though i did that before looking at the answer :p ) :)